# I want to retrieve the records in Mongodb for last 7 days for specific time. Like from 3-6 pm for last 7 days

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline

I want a query where I can get records for the last 7 days where events occurred between 3-6 pm

And timestamp is in unix so I tried

```
{ $expr: { $gte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 8 ], $lte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 18 ]} }

Error: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 8 ], $lte: [ { $hour: "$DateTime" }, 18 ] }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `$and`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $and: [
               { $gte: [{ $hour: "$DateTime" }, 8] },
               { $lte: [{ $hour: "$DateTime" }, 18] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: I tried this but ut is giving cannot convert bson type to string

Comment: Please provide some sample data.